# How to create notes/description based on custom Annotation to Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have a Springboot Rest application where I have annotation which is automatically converted API's and Params.

I have custom annotation where i include some notes to it, How can i get that generated to my swagger page in OpenAPI 3?

```
Ex:
@RestController
Class Controller {

@GetMapping(/test/result/)
@CustomAnnotation(value = "This description should come in swagger")
void method() {
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

SpringDoc allows you to customize the generated OpenAPI specification by implementing your own Customizer bean.

[There are plenty](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/tree/master/springdoc-openapi-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/core/customizers) of Customizer interfaces that you can use for customization, but the most usable are `OperationCustomizer`, `ParameterCustomizer`, and `PropertyCustomizer`.

Below is an example of Operation Customizer for your use case.

```
@Component
public class OperationCustomizer implements org.springdoc.core.customizers.OperationCustomizer {
    @Override
    public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
        CustomAnnotation annotation = handlerMethod.getMethodAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
        if (annotation != null) {
            operation.description(annotation.value());
        }
        return operation;
    }
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/tree/main/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/v30/app70) you can find an example of the project that uses custom annotations and Customizers for them.

[And here](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/tree/main/springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-api/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/v30/app92) an example of the project that modifies the generated specification based on the @NonNull annotation.

Comment: dead links, urls should be rewritten to https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/main/springdoc-openapi-starter-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/core/customizers/OperationCustomizer.java

Answer (score 0):

As @VadymVL pointed out a component extending `OperationCustomizer` is necessary:

```
@Component
public class CustomOperationCustomizer implements OperationCustomizer {
  @Override
  public Operation customize(Operation operation, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) {
      /* your code */
  }
```

Just don't forget to register it:

```
@Bean
  public GroupedOpenApi publicApi(CustomOperationCustomizer operationCustomizer) {
    return GroupedOpenApi.builder()
            .group(/*your group*/)
            .pathsToMatch(/*your endpoint*/)
            .
            /* anything else you need */
            .
            .addOperationCustomizer(operationCustomizer)
            .build();
  }
```

And you're good to go!